# How to append a dictionary value to an existing dictionary value?

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, append, key

Let's say I have a:

```
dict = {"Main": ["Tammy","Elisha","Julius"],
        "Elisha": ["Kenneth"]
       }
```

The context is like a Queue system. The Main is the normal queue. While "Elisha:[Kenneth]" is like a Cut queue. You can imagine everyone is queueing normally for a MacDonald when Elisha decided to bring his friend, Kenneth into the queue.

How do i append "Kenneth" to "Main":"Elisha" so that when I print dict['Main'] it will return the following expected output:

Expected Output: `[Tammy, Elisha, Kenneth, Julius ]`

If Elisha decided to bring in another friend, "Elisha": ["Nicole"]. Then the expected output would be:

Expected Output: `[ Tammy, Elisha, Kenneth, Nicole, Julius ]`

I tried googling for append, however append doesn't work for dictionary but only on list.

I tried:

```
dict['Main'].value("Elisha").append("Kenneth")
```

but it returned error.

Comment: Do you mean `dict = {"Main":["Tammy","Elisha","Julius"],

        "Elisha": "Kenneth"
       }` since your provided data structure is not valid

Comment: @Epsi95 yes, hahah i had made the edits. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recursively print the queue
How it works:

1. Make a empty queue
2. Start from the first person in the `Main` queue
3. Add that person to the empty queue mentioned in 1
4. Check if there is any friend of that person, if so
5. Add them in the queue mentioned in 1, and check their friends also if exists

```py
d = {"Main":["Tammy","Elisha","Julius"],

        "Elisha": ["Kenneth"]
       }

def get_flattened_queue(data, key, flattened_queue):
    members = data[key]
    for each_member in members:
        flattened_queue.append(each_member)
        if each_member in data.keys():
            get_flattened_queue(data, each_member, flattened_queue)
    return flattened_queue

flattened_queue = []
get_flattened_queue(d, 'Main', flattened_queue)

print(flattened_queue)
```

```
['Tammy', 'Elisha', 'Kenneth', 'Julius']
```

Now suppose `Elisa` brings `Nicole`

```
d = {"Main":["Tammy","Elisha","Julius"],

        "Elisha": ["Kenneth"]
       }

def get_flattened_queue(data, key, flattened_queue):
    members = data[key]
    for each_member in members:
        flattened_queue.append(each_member)
        if each_member in data.keys():
            get_flattened_queue(data, each_member, flattened_queue)
    return flattened_queue

# Here she brings Nicole
d['Elisha'].append('Nicole')

#{"Main":["Tammy","Elisha","Julius"],
#        "Elisha": ["Kenneth", "Nicole"]
#       }

flattened_queue = []
get_flattened_queue(d, 'Main', flattened_queue)

print(flattened_queue)
```

```
['Tammy', 'Elisha', 'Kenneth', 'Nicole', 'Julius']
```

---

```
d = {"Main":["Tammy","Elisha","Julius"],

        "Elisha": ["Kenneth"]
       }

def get_flattened_queue(data, key, flattened_queue):
    members = data[key]
    for each_member in members:
        flattened_queue.append(each_member)
        if each_member in data.keys():
            get_flattened_queue(data, each_member, flattened_queue)
    return flattened_queue

# Here she brings Nicole
d['Elisha'].append('Nicole')

#{"Main":["Tammy","Elisha","Julius"],
#        "Elisha": ["Kenneth", "Nicole"]
#       }

# Nicole brings Epsi95
d['Nicole'] = ['Epsi95']

flattened_queue = []
get_flattened_queue(d, 'Main', flattened_queue)

print(flattened_queue)
```

```
{'Main': ['Tammy', 'Elisha', 'Julius'],
 'Elisha': ['Kenneth', 'Nicole'],
 'Nicole': ['Epsi95']}


['Tammy', 'Elisha', 'Kenneth', 'Nicole', 'Epsi95', 'Julius']
```

Comment: @Fumin great, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: what if Nicole wants to bring her friend. Will this code work then? So now even Nicole's friend or nicole's friend can cut the queue

Comment: Certainly, check the answer, Nicole is adding epsi

Comment: A like will be appreciated than thank you ;) @Fumin

Comment: @epsi96 just realise, this code will not work if there is no CutQ at all. Meaning if everyone join by the MainQ, then this code woulnt work.

Comment: sorry im new to stackoverflow, how do i like?? i can only approve this answer. I cant upvote bcus there's certain requirements

Comment: Yes it should work, if everybody is in mainQ.

Comment: Can you provide one example where it did not work?

Comment: hmm abit hard to explain here, because this isnt the full code. But anyways i tried, it is okay.. now.. just some typo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `extend` for your case:

```
dic = {"Main":["Tammy","Elisha","Julius"],
        "Elisha": ["Kenneth", "Nicole"]
       }
dic["Main"].extend(dic["Elisha"])
print(dic["Main"])
```

Output:

```
['Tammy', 'Elisha', 'Julius', 'Kenneth', 'Nicole']
```

Also, avoid using keyword `dict` for object names to avoid shadowing in-build behavior.

Update:

To insert at a particular `index`, you can first use the `index()` method to get the index to be inserted at and then used slicing to insert the new list as:

```
idx = dic["Main"].index("Elisha")
dic["Main"][idx+1:len(dic["Elisha"])] = dic["Elisha"]
print(dic["Main"])

['Tammy', 'Elisha', 'Kenneth', 'Nicole', 'Julius']
```

Comment: Not the expected output. Kenneth and Nicole needs to come after Elisha.

Its like Queue system. Thank you thou @Krishna

Comment: I have added the implementation for the insertion at a particular index as well, please see the updated answer @Fumin

Comment: THank you, could u explain what do you mean by idx? I dont really understand your code. Thou your output seems to work.

Comment: `dic["Main"].index("Elisha")` will return the index where the element `Elisha` is present in the list and the value is stored in the object named `idx`. `dic["Main"][idx+1:len(dic["Elisha"])]` is used to insert the new list starting from `idx+1` location in the original list.